# in what way is a comparator superior to comparable?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, comparable

"How will you sort collection of employee objects by its id or name". For that we can use two interfaces, i.e., `Comparator and Comparable.` 
seems this is one of the common interview questions

But I don't see a reason why I should use both for sorting employee objects

I have been thinking on what `comparator` accomplishes that `Comparable` cannot do.
I understand that if the objects (instance variables that is compared upon) have natural ordering then `comparable` is the right choice.
but if custom ordering is needed (eg string length) then one could write a `comparator.`
my point here is `comparator` is only needed by the client if he wants to sort the data by some other criteria.
For example, I would implement an `Employee class` to sort by `id` using `comparable interface`.
but if the client wants to sort Employee objects by `String`(name), he would implement `comparator` either as a concrete class or anonymously in sorting.
Is there anything I am missing here?

For example, In the following code, for the Person object, my compareTo method, compares the age and sort it
In the compare method, I use String length (name of the person) for sorting. In theory, I could accomplish both in the compareTo method as I have implemented below.

lastly, are there any added benefits of one of the following over other
I have implemented comparator in two ways
1. as a static method which is commented out
2. as anonymous object(?) in the main method which is commented out
3. make a new class that implements comparator and call the instance of that class in collections.sort() -- this I have not done here

```
(The commented-out parts of the code works. They are just different implementations)

mport java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.*;

public class PersonComparator implements Comparable{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public PersonComparator(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "name=" + name + ", age=" + age;
}

/*@Override
public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof PersonComparator)) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Invalid object");
    }
    PersonComparator p2 = (PersonComparator)obj;
    return this.age-p2.age;
}*/

/*Alternative CompareTo that checks for both age and name*/
 public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof PersonComparator)) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Invalid object");
    }
    PersonComparator p2 = (PersonComparator)obj;
    if (this.age!=p2.age){
        return this.age-p2.age;
    }
    else {
    return (this.name.length()-p2.name.length());
}
} 


/*public static Comparator nameLengthComparator 
= new Comparator() {


    @Override
    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        if (!(obj1 instanceof PersonComparator) || !(obj2 instanceof PersonComparator)){
            throw new ClassCastException("Invalid object");
        }
        else {
            PersonComparator p1 = (PersonComparator)obj1;
            PersonComparator p2 = (PersonComparator)obj2;
            return p1.name.length()-p2.name.length();
        }
}
};*/

 public static void main(String[] args){
     PersonComparator p1 = new PersonComparator("Alexander", 45);
     PersonComparator p2 = new PersonComparator("Pat", 27);
     PersonComparator p3 = new PersonComparator("Zacky", 45);
     PersonComparator p4 = new PersonComparator("Rake", 34);

     List<PersonComparator> list = new ArrayList<PersonComparator>();
     list.add(p1);
     list.add(p2);
     list.add(p3);
     list.add(p4);

     System.out.println("Before sorting "+ list);
     Collections.sort(list);
     //System.out.println("After sorting by age "+ list);
     //System.out.println("Before sorting "+ list);
     //Collections.sort(list, nameLengthComparator);
     System.out.println("After sorting by name length "+ list);
     /*Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<PersonComparator>() {
         @Override
            public int compare(PersonComparator p1, PersonComparator p2) {
                    return p1.name.length()-p2.name.length();
                }
        }
    );*/
     System.out.println("After sorting by name length "+ list);
 }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is what you say... btw use `Comparable<T>` with generics  to be type safe rather than using `Object`

Comment: Using the Comparable interface single sorting order can be defined for the objects of a class. 
Comparator interface is used to define multiple sorting orders for the objects of a class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## `Comparable` interface

The `Comparable` interface defines a type's *natural ordering*. Suppose you have a list of `String` or `Integer` objects; you can pass that list to

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

and you will have a sorted list. How? Because `String` and `Integer` both implement `Comparable` interface and the implementations of `Comparable` interface provide a *natural ordering*. Its like the class definition saying  - "**If you find a collection of objects of my type, order them according to the strategy I have defined in the `compareTo` method**".

Now when you define your own type, you can define the *natural ordering* of the objects of your class by implementing the `Comparable` interface. [See the Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) for more information on object ordering.

## `Comparator` interface

The `Comparator` interface describes how to define custom strategies for object ordering. Suppose we have a simple `Person` type as below:

```
public class Person {
    String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Now, by implementing the `Comparator` interface, you can write different strategies to order the instances of your `Person` type. For example, consider the two strategies for ordering `Person` objects given below:

```
class StrategyOne implements Comparator<Person> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getName().length() - p2.getName().length();
    }

}

class StrategyTwo implements Comparator<Person> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }

}
```

Here, `StrategyOne` will order `Person` objects based on the length of their names, and `StrategyTwo` will order `Person` objects based on lexicographic ordering of their names.

### The ways to implement `Comparator`

As you can see, the concrete strategy classes are *stateless*, hence all instances are functionally equivalent. So, we just need a single instance of any concrete strategy class. Thus, it should be a singleton. Using anonymous classes will create a new instance each time the call is executed. **Consider storing the object in a private static final field and reusing it by using static factory methods to access them** [**Effective Java**]. For example, you can reuse the above two concrete strategies as below:

```
class Strategies {
    private static final Comparator<Person> PERSON_NAME_LENGTH_COMPARATOR = new StrategyOne();

    private static final Comparator<Person> PERSON_NAME_LEXICAL_COMPARATOR = new StrategyTwo();

    public static Comparator<Person> personNameLengthComparator(){
         return  PERSON_NAME_LENGTH_COMPARATOR;
    }


    public static Comparator<Person> personNameLexicalComparator(){
         return  PERSON_NAME_LEXICAL_COMPARATOR;
    }
}
```

## Summary

To summarize, the `Comparable` interface is used to define the natural ordering of a class, and the `Comparator` interface is used to define particular strategies for object ordering.

Comment: "Consider storing the object in a private static final field and reusing it by using static factory methods to access them"- good point, following guidelines of `effective java by Joshua Bloch`

Comment: what do you mean by "As you can see, the concrete strategy classes are stateless, hence all instances are functionally equivalent."

Comment: @user1988876 : We are not maintaining any state in our strategy classes.So they are stateless. The return value of the `compare` method depends on the argument values passed to it, its operation does not depend on the **state** of the object as it does not have any.It does not matter how many objects of our strategy classes we are creating, the `compare` method of all of them will return the same value for the same set of parameters. Hence we can say that **Stateless classes are always functionally equivalent**.

Comment: Awesome post !!

Answer (score 8):

> In what way is a comparator superior to comparable?

It is not "superior".  It is just that the two interfaces are doing (roughly) the same thing in different ways.  In the `Comparable` case the ordering logic is in the object being ordered.  In the `Comparator` case, the logic is in a different class from the objects being declared.

> But I don't see a reason why I should use both for sorting employee objects

The only case where it would make sense to use *both* would be if you needed to be able to sort the objects into different orders.  Then you could declare the relevant classes as implementing `Comparable` for the "natural" order and use `Comparator` objects to implement the other orders.

By the way, a comparator *probably should not* implement `Comparable`, and vice versa.

If a comparator implements `Comparable` that implies you are trying to order instances of the comparator object itself ...

Your `PersonComparator` class is misnamed.  It should really be called `Person`.

---

> Could you clarify one thing in your answer that we have already `equals()` method from Object class then why the `Comparator` interface is facilitating the `equals()` method again?

A number of points:

- You still seem to be confusing the purpose of `Comparable` and `Comparator`.  The `equals` method on a `Comparator` object compares the comparator with other comparators!!
- The `equals` method tells you whether two objects are equal ... not which one comes first.
- The reason that `Comparator` overrides `equals` is *solely* so that [they can clearly document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) what `equals(Object)` does when you call it on a `Comparator` object.  (The actual behaviour is entirely consistent with `Object.equals(Object)` ... but they obviously thought it necessary to do this because programmers were repeatedly getting the semantics of the method wrong.)

Comment: Could you clarify one thing in your answer that we have already equals() method from Object class then why the Comparator interface is facilitating the equals() method again ?

Comment: +1 for the statement **Comparable** :- "Ordering logic is in the object itself being ordered" and in **Comparator** :- "Ordering logic is in different class from objects to be sorted "

Answer (score 4):

> In what way is a comparator superior to comparable?

I won't say it is superior but one advantage is that it enables us to write multiple sort sequences. In case of `Comparable`, you would have to implement that interface by your class which you want to sort and you can write only one sort sequence.

With `Comparator`, you can make different classes for sort sequences and while sorting, you just pass the `Comparator` instance to `COllections.sort()` method.

Consider `Employee` class which has fields `id`, `firstName` and `lastName`. If you implement `Comparable`, you can write only one sorting logic in `compareTo` method.

If you implement `Comparator` then you can create separate sorting sequences by creating separate classes. e.g. `IdSorter`, `FirstNameSorter` and `LastNameSorter` which gives you way to sort `Employee` in multiple ways.

Read

[Sorting user defined objects with Comparator](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-2/)

Answer (score 3):

Comparable allows you to sort items in a collections based on only one field.Comparator provides the flexibility to compare items based on more than one field

For example.

```
class Person implements Comparable
{

int age;
String name;


Person(int age,String name)
{
   this.age=age;
   this.name=name;
}

public int compareTo(Object o1)   // Either you can compare according to age or name
{
    Person p = (Person)o1;
    if (this.age==p.age)
    return 0;
    else if (this.age>p.age)
    return 1;
    else
    return -1;
}


public int compareTo(Object o)    //Based on name comparision
{
     return (this.name.compareTo((Person)o).name));
}
public static void main (String args[])
{
     List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
     Person o = new Person(12,"Steve");
     Person o1 = new Person(13,"Jason");
     list.add(o);
     list.add(o1);
     Collections.sort(list);
    }
}
```

In case of Comparable above, you can sort items either using age or name.But in case of Comparator ,you can sort the items based on more than one field.

```
class AgeComparison implements Comparator
{
   public int compare(Object o1,Object o2)
{
        Person s1 = (Person)o1;
        Person s2 =(Person)o2;
        if (s1.age==s2.age)
        return 0;
        if(s1.age>s2.age)
        return 1;
        else
        return -1;
}

class NameComparison implements Comparator
{
     public int compare(Object o1,Object o2)
    {
        Person s1 = (Person)o1;
        Person s2 =(Person)o2;
        return (s1.age.compareTo(s2.age));
    }

}
```

To use Comparator, you have to pass the list and the instance of class you have to use.

```
Collections.sort(list,new NameComparison());
Collections.sort(list,new AgeComparison());
```

In a nutshell, the advantage of Comparator is the flexibility to sort the list based on more than one field of the object.

Answer (score 0):

In general, use Comparable when the ordering is "obvious".  E.g., for Strings you use alphabetical, for numbers you use numeric order. Note that a Comparable object *can only implement a single compareTo()* method, so you only get one option - the "natural", "obvious" option.  The advantage is that it is simple and client code doesn't have to do any extra work to compare things.

Use Comparator if the ordering is less obvious, or you might want to have multiple options.  For example, a Book might get sorted by Title, Author, ISBN, etc.  You could have three different Comparators to handle those three cases.  You might want to sort Strings by some unusual order, e.g. a special case for a foreign language, ignoring capitals, etc.

Also, if the Objects you are sorting do not implement Comparable, or you are mixing types that  do not like to compare to each other (in general, this is to be avoided, but perhaps you want to be able to compare Books and Authors in a single list in some special case) you need to use Comparator.

Comment: Actually, even with strings the ordering isn't necessarily obvious.  Depending upon what the strings represent, there are at least four different ways one might reasonably wish to sort "X4.9", "X10.3", and "X4.12".  Or, for that matter, "Hello", "HI", and "HEY".

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... I have already written a lot on this clarification aided with pictures and explanations.

Please find the link below:

[Comparable and Comparator](http://techieme.in/comparable-and-comparato/)

One think you can always remember and that is "they can’t be used interchangeably"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using comparator , you just need to add one comparator class and pass it to Collections.sort() method along with List object no other change in existing code.

but if you implement comparable interface you will have to change code of all the model/bean classes to override compareTo() method.

so **for Loose Coupling comparator is better.**